# Unable to assign output of command to a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

---

I have a update.sh file which has below command.

```
shyaml get-value  platform < ~/mcp_version/latest-versions.yaml
```

I am able to run the command through terminal, also the command runs from script.

Below is the content of script

```
echo "The platform is $now"
echo "PATH is '$PATH'"
platform = $(shyaml get-value  platform < ~/mcp_version/latest-versions.yaml)
echo "The platform is $platform"
shyaml get-value  platform < ~/mcp_version/latest-versions.yaml
```

But when I try to assign the output of the command to a variable then it gives error. as

```
./update.sh: line 12: platform: command not found
```

Below is the output when I run my script.

```
bash-4.2$ ./update.sh 
The platform is Fri Jul 12 11:57:25 IST 2019
PATH is '/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin/:/usr/bin/shyaml'
./update.sh: line 12: platform: command not found
The platform is 
19.06.00bash-4.2$
```

Comment: Remove space before and after equal.

Comment: For the future, use https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is the first comment by @Prvt_Yadv:

> Remove space before and after equal

Wrong:

```
platform = something
```

Correct:

```
platform=something
```